# How do I design an asynchronous notification sending application?

Tags: java, spring, algorithm, time, microservices

I am working on an asynchronous notification sending application in Spring. For this purpose, I have two services. The first service receives the content, timing, and other information of the notification from the frontend and writes it to the database. In the second service, I want to periodically check the timing of notifications and send the notifications whose time has come to the other service. How can I accomplish this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can use ActiveMQ for Async notifications.
The first service puts a message with the scheduled time and when that time arrives the message will dequeue automatically on the second service. then you can continue as per your further logic

ref. : https://activemq.apache.org/delay-and-schedule-message-delivery

I hope it works for you. or let me know for more clarification if needed

Comment: I tried using Kafka. In the Producer, I produced a message and sent it to Kafka. The Consumer received the message and performed a time check. If the time had come, it sent the message to the other service; if not, it sent it back to Kafka. However, the issue here was that messages whose time had not come were continuously being added to the queue. Would I encounter the same issue with the method you provided?

Comment: ActiveMQ and Kafka both support JMS. But here it seems ActiveMQ is more suitable for you as per your use case. you can decide which is better for you from the link.[link]https://www.openlogic.com/blog/kafka-vs-activemq.  By ActiveMQ, you can get this 1. receive a message when its time comes. 2. if when message comes and some exception occurs (based on your use case) so you can easily transfer back to the same queue by session. Rollback() method. if you called the session. Acknowledge() then the message will be marked as dequeue other wise message will remain in the same queue.